# NodeJS - Cannot find custom module in Linux. Works fine in windows

Tags: node.js, linux, node-modules

The below is my folder struture

```
--package.json
--node_modules
--dist
--server.js
----app
------driver
------utils
```

Inside 'driver' folder I have driver.model.ts file which references BaseValidator

```
import { BaseValidator } from '../utils/BaseValidator';
export class LoginDriverModel extends BaseValidator {
...
}
```

Inside the 'utils' folder I have a file called BaseValidator.ts like

```
export class BaseValidator {
}
```

Now when I run below commands in windows and linux after setting environment variable NODE_ENV=dev

```
node server.js    [works fine in windows]
nodejs server.js  [uncaughtException: Cannot find module '../utils/BaseValidator' in Linux]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to happen in Linux if we have the same file name and class name, in the same case. The issue got resolved after changing the file name from 'BaseValidator.ts' to 'baseValidator.ts'.

Referencing the class is like below,

```
import { BaseValidator } from '../utils/baseValidator';
export class LoginDriverModel extends BaseValidator {
...
}
```